# How to use the microphone on Android

Tags: android

I have just started to develop my first Android app, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to start the microphone and have it listen, which is a main feature of my app.

I've searched the Android docs and I can't find much info on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this can help (actually from the Android docs):
[Audio Capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

1. Create a new instance of `android.media.MediaRecorder`.
2. Set the audio source using `MediaRecorder.setAudioSource()`. You will probably want to use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC`.
3. Set output file format using `MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat()`.
4. Set output file name using `MediaRecorder.setOutputFile()`.
5. Set the audio encoder using `MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder()`.
6. Call `MediaRecorder.prepare()` on the `MediaRecorder` instance.
7. To start audio capture, call `MediaRecorder.start()`.
8. To stop audio capture, call `MediaRecorder.stop()`.
9. When you are done with the `MediaRecorder` instance, call `MediaRecorder.release()` on it. Calling `MediaRecorder.release()` is always recommended to free the resource immediately.

or:
[Android Audio Recording Tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

Comment: I think this example is a very good one!: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom recorder:

```
 final static int RQS_RECORDING = 1; 
 Uri savedUri; 
 Button buttonRecord;

 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    buttonRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record);
    buttonRecord.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == RQS_RECORDING) {
         savedUri = data.getData();
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
         "Saved: " + savedUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but it's better to explain something to a beginner