# Background Access to Microphone in Android

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-hardware

Is it possible to be constantly monitoring the microphone from a background application (service?) on an Android phone?

Some idea of what I want to do:

- Listen constantly for an audible signal in the background.
- Upon receipt of 'interesting' audio signal, perform some network operation.

The background application must be able to intelligently relinquish access to the microphone should a foreground application require it (unless it can be shared?) - e.g. to make a call.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Recording audio is possible check out these links:

[Record audio](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

[Record audio](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

Got them from this post [How to use the microphone on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564495/how-to-use-the-microphone-on-android) .

So I'm thinking it should be possible to record inside an background service. Don't got the time atm to verify it.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't want to record the audio. I will just need to stream and buffer the audio (probably a few seconds worth) to search for an encoded audio signal. - And the service must be able to relinquish any exclusive locks on microphone access should a foreground application require it.

Comment: @Avram i want the same thing you want , what did you end up with , is there a way to do that ? please help

Comment: @Avram any progress you had on this front ?? or ny other leads you can provide.. ?

Comment: Sorry, nothing to add. I didn't end up implementing this and am no longer working on it.