# android microphone speak activity (speech) - not recording

Tags: android, audio, stream, microphone

i try to get the activity of the internal microphone from an android phone, check out if somebody is speaking. I already tried out the MediaRecorder, but there i have to record it and its not realtime, like here:

[How to use the microphone on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564495/how-to-use-the-microphone-on-android)

thanks!

Comment: What's your question? You can use `AudioRecord` to continuously get PCM data from the microphone which you can analyze and throw away.

Comment: thanks, i did not realized it, i just thought its only for record, i will check it out