# Android - How to test if the microphone is working

Tags: android

I'm working on a diagnosis app, I want to know how can I test that the microphone is working properly? I tried looking but could not find any code.
From working properly i mean that its not broken and it functions properly. Is there any way?

Comment: You haven't described the physical environment in which you intend to perform this test. You also haven't defined what "working" means. The most basic of tests would be to record while playing something through the loudspeaker, and check if the waveform has a non-zero amplitude.

Comment: @Michael can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the microphone on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564495/how-to-use-the-microphone-on-android)

Comment: make a sound recorder, and play the recorded sound, if it plays , then it is working, make something that user will judge that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) Class. You will presumably want to record something for a few seconds and then play it back (this would test the speakers too). You will need the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```